# accessing session variable inside a response transformer in gatling

Tags: gatling

I have a basic question for which I don't seem to be able to find the answer. How can I access session variables inside a response transformer? Something like:

```
.transformResponse {
      case response if response.isReceived =>
        new ResponseWrapper(response) {
          session??
          override val body = new ByteArrayResponseBody("", UTF_8)
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `Session` object in context of that partial function, so you can't access it. What do you want to achieve? Maybe `check(bodyString.transform())` would be better solution as it can take `(String, Session) => T` as parameter so you can access session attributes in that function.

Comment: yeah that worked. I needed it because in one call I get an encryption key that I need in subsequent calls to decrypt response body. Transforming the response was the right thing for my case. Thanks!